# Hashcode returning unexpected results

Tags: java, hashcode

I am trying to use HashTable (I have to use hashing) in order to store a telephone directory. I want to sort the telephone entries as they enter based on surname (alphabetically). I decided to use as a key to the HashTable the hashCode of the first character of the surname in an entry.

This is the hashCode I wrote in the Entry class:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int index= getSurname().charAt(0);
    return index;
}
```

And this is the addEntry method which is used to add new entries to the directory:

```java
@Override
public void addEntry(Entry line) {
    //Throws an exception if either surname, initials or number are null.
    if (line.getSurname()==null||line.getInitial()==null||line.getNumber()==null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Surname, Initials and a Number");
    }

    //Throws an exception if initials are less than 2
    if (line.getInitial().length() < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please make sure that initials include both first name and surname eg: AK");
    }

    //Throws an exception if the length of the number is not 5 characters.
    if (line.getNumber().length() != 5) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Number that is 5 characters long (make sure that it starts with 0)");
    }

    //Throws an exception if the number doesnt start with 0.
    if (line.getNumber().startsWith("0") == false) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Number must start with a 0");
    }

    //Initialises the key using the hashCode of surname.
    int key=line.getSurname().hashCode();

    //If statement checks if the HashTable entries contains the key
    if (entries.contains(key)){
        //If it does it creates a linkedList called list
        LinkedList<Entry> list =new LinkedList();

        list=entries.get(key);
        ListIterator<Entry> iterator = list.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            int x=0;
            String one = list.get(x).getSurname();

            if (one.compareToIgnoreCase(line.getSurname()) > 0){
                entries.put(x,list);
                x++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        LinkedList<Entry> list2 =new LinkedList();
        list2.add(line);
        entries.put(key,list2);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I did some testing to see the results of adding different entries i found that the key (hashCode) is not generated correctly.

These are the results:

```
Key: -2083437938. Value: [Entry{surname='Jansas initials=KJ Phone number=05544'}]
Key: -1911680082. Value: [Entry{surname='Paul initials=AP Phone number=05572'}]
Key: 66344. Value: [Entry{surname='Aza initials=AZ Phone number=05212'}]
Key: 867699843. Value: [Entry{surname='Penny initials=KP Phone number=05271'}]
Key: 1953849949. Value: [Entry{surname='Aanais initials=AP Phone number=05562'}]
```

Shouldnt the entry with surname "Aza" be over "Penny"and next to "Aanais"? Any ideas on how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You are trying to bodge the hashing function to implement a table that is ordered by surname (or at least the first character of the surname) - this is not what hashing is for.  A much simpler solution would be to wrap the surname, initials and phone number into a class that implements `Comparable` and use a data-structure that is automatically sorted such as `TreeSet` or programatically sort the data using `Collections::sort`. No need then to come up with a custom solution that violates the hash code contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```java
...
int key=line.getSurname().hashCode();
...
```

And when I saw it correctly, the `line` variable is of type `Entry` and you override the `hashCode` in that `Entry` class. The the above snipped should be

```java
...
int key=line.hashCode();
...
```

Otherwise you use the `hashCode` method of class `String` (or whatever `getSurname` returns).

However this is not a good implementation for a Java hash code, which is not design for your usecase. I would reconsider the approach you use here for sorting things.